# Solution of ODE $u''+4u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Just doing some revision for ODEs and came across this problem. Find the general solution to $$u''+4u=0.$$

So far I've applied the characteristic polynomial:
$$\begin{array}{r c l}
\lambda^2 +4 & = & 0 \\
\lambda^2 & = & -4 \\
\lambda & = & i\sqrt{4} \\
\lambda & = & 2i, -2i. \\
\end{array}$$

So the general solution should be:
$$\begin{array}{l c l}
u_H & = & Ae^{2ix}+Be^{-2ix} \\
& = & A(\cos{2x}+i\sin{2x})+B(\cos{(-2x)}+i\sin{(-2x)}) \\
& = & A\cos{2x}+iA\sin{2x}+B\cos{2x}-iB\sin{2x} \\
& = & (A+B)\cos{2x}+i(A-B)\sin{2x} \\
& = & C_1\cos{2x}+iC_2\sin{2x}. \\
\end{array}$$

The answers have $u=C_1\cos{2x}+C_2\sin{2x}$, and my question is "what happened to the $i$?" Does it drop out somewhere or is there an error in the answers?

Many thanks for a quick explanation/link to the appropriate website explaining this. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$i$ is a constant, and so is included in $C_2$. So you're both right! :)

Answer (score 3):

If we wrote:

$$\tag 1 e^{a+ 2i} = e^{a t}(\cos 2t + i \sin 2t)v_1$$

where $v_1$ is the eigenvector, and for your problem $a = 0$.

When we expand $(\cos 2t + i \sin 2t)v_1$, we get an expression of the form:

$$(\alpha) + i(\beta)$$

Because we know that the real imaginary parts are both solutions, we have:

$$c_1(\alpha) + c_2(\beta).$$

Comment: Nice observations my dear friend+

Comment: @BabakS.: Even though the answer is a bit cryptic, it won't be appreciated until the OP has to use eigenvalues/vectors to write out solutions. Hope all is well. Regards!

Comment: @BabakS.: This was an interesting problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458105/constructing-a-non-linear-system-with-prerequisites-about-the-nature-of-its-crit

Comment: Hello, Amzoti! (+1) ;-)